# allowing users to access certain ports on server

Tags: networking, permissions, rhel, access-control

I have an RHEL 6 system which has 20 users. I have 20 ports on which separate versions of a service is running. I want user a to access port a, but not other ports. Is there a way to do this? (possibly by modifying iptables)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "owner" iptables module to do this. As an example to restrict port 999 to the user 'fred' only you can use:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 999 -j REJECT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 999 -m owner --uid-owner fred -j ACCEPT
```

The above rules are inserted to the top of the OUTPUT chain so the order reject then accept.

Comment: Also works for me on ubuntu server! Thanks!