# ssh port forwarding, who has access to localhost?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, loopback

I've done an ssh remote port forwarding:

`me@host1.a.com% ssh -R 127.0.0.1:11999:host2.a.com:99 me@host3.b.com`
My understanding is that this creates a TCP socket on host3.b.com's localhost port 11999.

I then checked that from host3.b.com I can indeed access the service exposed at host3.b.com's localhost port 11999.

I've also checked that I can login to `host3.b.com` with a different ssh session (thus creating a new login shell) and can also access the service exposed at host3.b.com's localhost port 11999.  This kind of scares me.  I naively thought I'd get a different loopback interface for each login shell, but apparently not.

My question is: what about other people who can log into `host3.b.com` like my friend `buddy` and my enemy `aHacker`?  Do they get assigned to the same loopback interface that I get when I log into `host3.b.com`?  Or do they get their own private loopback interfaces and can't see my open port on my host3.b.com's localhost:11999?  Is there a way to make sure that I'm the only user who can access a forwarded port?

Comment: I never heard of a `different loopback interface for each login` unless I'm mistaken there is no such thing as a "different loopback interface" for each login let alone user.

Comment: You will need to do some authentication on your service that sits on port 11999 and control user behaviour that way.

Comment: _Maybe_ you can block certain users (or allow) with a software firewall solution on your host server. But it's definitely good design to authenticate someone over a connection _anyway_.

Comment: The service actually does do user authentication.  Unfortunately, I'm going to have to shut off the port forwarding because the service is behind a firewall, and the owners of the server view the firewall as being an important aspect of the security.

Comment: I thought the TCP socket would have the same user access control as a UNIX socket, and it clearly doesn't.  If I could just get my client to communicate over a UNIX socket instead of a TCP socket, I could use ssh to forward a UNIX socket instead of a TCP socket and I'd be fine, but I don't think the client supports UNIX sockets, just TCP sockets.

Comment: It's a good question nonetheless it's actually a good idea to restrict access to resources as much as possible. I just think this isn't possible without a firewall solution since ports are OS-wide (and not _tied_ to a specific user). I don't think you can achieve this with UNIX sockets, since you'll need TCP/IP for forwarding/routing the traffic through the internet.

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111906/allowing-users-to-access-certain-ports-on-server) might be able to solve your problem. It involves `iptables` and permitting/denying access to a specific port on a per user basis.